# put restrictions on Pattern for passwords in yang model

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, yang

There is the following requirement in the definition of password in yang model.
Have a password  which has at least one lower case , one upper case ,a special character, a digit and at least 8 characters.
I defile the leaf password as following

```
leaf password {
            
             type string
            {
                pattern "/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,}$/";
            }
}
```

But error is generated

yangvalidator-v2-workdir-iuyWhcOX/tcs_parameters.yang:95: warning: the escape sequence "\d" is unsafe in double quoted strings - pass the flag --lax-quote-checks to avoid this warning
yangvalidator-v2-workdir-iuyWhcOX/tcs_parameters.yang:95: error: syntax error in pattern: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}pattern': The value '/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[#$@!%&*?])[A-Za-z\d#$@!%&*?]{8,30}$/' of the facet 'pattern' is not a valid regular expression., line 6

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to use a regex flavor not supported by YANG (evident from your usage of constructs such as `/regex/`, `^regex$`, `?=`, etc.). You need to use **XML Schema (XSD) regular expressions**. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70360140/878469) for details.

Rather than storing passwords into your datastore as plain text, consider using the `binary` built in YANG type, which stores a properly secured secret (the end result of some algorithm outside of YANG modeling scope). Unless you are using YANG to model something very specific using extensions such as sx:structure (RFC 8791), which seems unlikely.